# docker swarm nodes prefer to use own container first before going to use other node's container in global mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, swarm

i have 3 swarm managers node without any worker node in global mode
this makes each node have exactly one container.

when i send request to any node, that request may be processed by any of the container but i want to create priority that it should preferably be executed by the container of that node which i send request.
and if the container connot respond, it should use the container of the other nodes.

i use chatgpt to get my answer and it says you can use --placement-pref but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Swarms mesh networking is very simple and does a simple round robin load balancing.

If this is not wanted you can either use host mode networking, or for service to service calls you could use `tasks.<service>` to get the DNSRR record, or a different mesh implementation like Hashicorp Consul. (Not that Hashicorp Consul necessarily implements your use case).